# Are rewards from the clan chest proportional to what you have put in?

Tags: clash-royale

When you have a clan on Clash Royale, at the top of the screen appears a Clan Chest, which members of the clan have to fill with crowns. Due to my clan being inactive, I have put in about 100 crowns, and no other member has put in even one.

How will the rewards of the chest be distributed? Will I get more because I have added the most crowns to it, or does everyone get the same amount even if they have not contributed anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clan chest rewards are totally random!

The only need for getting it is to contribute at least one crown to the chest.

About inactive members of your clan, if they didn't bring 1 crown to the chest, they won't earn anything!

Let's say you got 10/10 Chest, you will earn about 270 cards, 27 Rares & 2 Epics (chance for legendary) according to your current arena.